# using jquery (json) to get ajax database entries in wordpress - PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for my wordpress site and am having trouble understanding the jquery ajax requests. In a nutshell, I am trying to get some user meta data loaded when the page loads.

So in my javascript file I have a line:

```
$.getJSON("http://mysite.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/ajax/ajax.php?action=test", function(json) { // do stuff });
```

So the above DOES get called, but it's the PHP code I'm having trouble with. In the file ajax.php, I am making a database call, but NONE of the usual class information is available. I've tried including the admin ajax page, various other pages from my own plugin (which does work).... not sure what else to do!

The database call method works OK in my plugin code.. but I guess that the ajax.php file is outside the WP framework so that's why it's not working... but I don't know how to get it IN the framework!?

I just need to use the `$wpdb->get_results($sql);` command to get my SQL. The error returned from firebug is that I am making a call to an undefined function.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: What did `alert(json)` give you?

Comment: actually, absolutely nothing. I've edited my PHP script to simply echo "hello"... that is returned as I can see the response in firebug (in firefox).

Comment: Did you check your error logs to see if PHP reported any errors?

Comment: well I know that it's a problem with PHP as my code returns the error. I simply need to know how to query the wordpress database outside of the framework... not sure what I am doing wrong!

Comment: @Matt - Is the JSON coming back valid?  Check it here: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: @Nick - I'm getting somewhere now - my json response is always 0. That is doing alert(json). Something's not right....!

Comment: I am going to post another question, as it's technically a new one with regards to my jquery issue now... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), basically you only need to define a callback for an action and use the already defined Wordpress machinery.

Comment: thanks - I have read that page before, but never ACTUALLY REALLY read it.... Just spent some time and now I understand. I've hooked in to the admin as it suggested which is possibly working... just trying to establish a good json connection first, then will test the $wpdb class ... which I am sure will be ok to use. Many thanks.